# Permanently hide caret in CRichEditCtrl

Tags: winapi

I'm using a `CRichEditCtrl` to display and interact with rich text, but want it to not show a caret at all.

I could possibly intercept every message and use `HideCaret()` to always hide the caret, but this seems like a hack at best, and am hoping there is a general solution that gets rid of the caret entirely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this is to create a subclass of `CRichEditCtrl` that overrides `OnSetFocus` to call `HideCaret()`.

Comment: Yes, this was essentially what I ended up doing.